# How to delay a login iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Within my app, I have functionality that requires you to log into a cloud to push data up to the cloud. This is a multithreaded app with encryption and posting up to the cloud inside of the dispatch queue. All works perfectly, except for one thing. When a user triggers an "Action listener" or method, upon clicking a button, they have to click the button twice to perform an action upon a successful login. I only want them to have to click the button once and insert the data. The user defaults checks to see if a user name is stored. Here's what the code looks like:

```
- (void)addNotesButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    // go to the add notes page


    NSString * loginResult = [self userDefaultsReturn:@"UserName"];

    //NSString * uID = [textDef stringForKey:@"UID"];


    if (loginResult == nil) {


        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Login" message:@"Please log into the cloud." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Login",@"Forgot Password",@"Sign Up", nil];

        [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleDefault];
        [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];


        [alert show];


        } else {
        //This is where I am confused. Needs to execute upon a successful log in. 

        AddNotesViewController *add = [[AddNotesViewController alloc] init];

        _product = [DBUserConnector fetchBookmarkStatus:_key_id subType:_subType];

        add.varShouldInsert=(!_product)?YES:NO;
        add.key_id=_key_id;
        add.subType=_subType;
        add.desc=(_product)?_product.detail:@"";
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:add animated:YES];

    }




}
```

I use the UIAlerviewAppDelegate method called "clickedButtonAtIndex" to retrieve user input and process the login request as I was explaining earlier. My problem is that if a user is not logged into the cloud, the else clause is not triggered (I fully acknowledge the reason why the else clause does not trigger, hear me out.) Currently, they have to click the button twice to trigger the else clause upon a successfully login. So how can I delay code to wait and check to see if a user logs in successfully. Also after a successful log in, insert the desired code? Hopefully I explained clearly enough for everyone. Thanks!

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to execute a while loop until a user successfully logged in, but it seems to be a waste of resources that way.

Comment: So, when they login successfully, you want it to push AddNotesViewController? That's it?

Comment: Yes. That's correct, pretty simple I know. Problem is the main thread executes the else statement when the alert view is presented. I just am wondering what's the most efficient way to go about it. My brain is thinking I can place a while loop on another thread. But I am worried the while loop will go crazy and eat up the CPU. Hopefully what I am saying makes sense.

Comment: I should say the main thread acknowledges the else statement, but does not execute it. If that brings more clarity. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the code that performs the Add Notes action to a separate method:

```
- (void)addNotes {
    AddNotesViewController *add = [[AddNotesViewController alloc] init];

    _product = [DBUserConnector fetchBookmarkStatus:_key_id subType:_subType];

    add.varShouldInsert=(!_product)?YES:NO;
    add.key_id=_key_id;
    add.subType=_subType;
    add.desc=(_product)?_product.detail:@"";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:add animated:YES];
}
```

Then keep track of what the intended action was before the user was prompted to log in.  Something like:

```
if (loginResult == nil) {

    self.postLoginAction = @selector(addNotes);

    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Login" message:@"Please log into the cloud." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Login",@"Forgot Password",@"Sign Up", nil];

    [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleDefault];
    [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];


    [alert show];

} else {
    [self addNotes];
}
```

Now when you get a callback that the login was successful you can perform whatever selector you saved in `self.postLoginAction`.

Just remember to clean up appropriately in the unsuccessful cases.  You don't want to run `addNotes` if the user was not able to log in; or if the user gave up, went to another screen, then logged in from there!

Comment: Good answer. Just need help understanding what self.postLoginAction means.

Comment: self.postLoginAction would be a SEL type: @property (nonatomic, assign) SEL postLoginAction;  To run the method you would want to use [self performSelector:self.postLoginAction];

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to write your code after the login process. As you said, you do that on the `clickedButtonAtIndex` method. In that same method, considering a successful login, you just present the `AddNotesViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably calling your login method and not waiting for a message from a completion handler.

You need to call the login method and then in the completion handler do all the other processing you need based on the success, or failure, of the login.

If you are using NSURLSession have a look at [URL Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html).

If you are using some other library it will have a callback process to let you know if your operation has completed successfully.